# Dynamic header in react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, header, navigation, react-navigation

I am using the functional approach with `react-navigation` v5.0.0, and I have a stack-navigator which contains:

```
App.js

<Stack.Screen
   name="Profil"
   component={Profile}
   options={{
      headerStyle: {
         backgroundColor: '#2270b9'
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
         color: 'white'
      },
      headerRight: () => (
         <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Ionicons
               style={{ color: 'white', marginRight: 15, marginTop: 5 }}
               size={32}
               onPress={() => { _sendMessage(...) }}            // <--- problem is here
               name="ios-mail"
               backgroundColor="#CCC"
            />
         </View>
      )
   }}
/>
```

Profile component looks roughly like this:

```
Profile.js

export default function Profile({ route, navigation }) {
   const { profile } = route.params;

   return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
         <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
   [...]
```

Now the problem is, `Profile` gets initialized with a payload object ("profile"), when the profile is opened:

```
Search.js / Visitors.js

navigation.navigate('Profil', { profile });
```

And the issue is, the send-button which is added in `App.js` needs the profile object which is passed to the `Profile.js` as route param, but it is not available in `App.js`.

How can I thus create the header button within `Profile` component, so I can access the profile object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try modifying your options prop to take route as parameter, like so:

```
options={({ route: { params: { profile } } }) => ({
  /** use profile here */
})
```

To put it in context of your App.js, note how options is a function taking { route } as parameter and returning your options object.

```
<Stack.Screen
   name="Profil"
   component={Profile}
   options={({ route: { params: { profile } } }) => ({ // <- Note that options in now a function
      headerStyle: {
         backgroundColor: '#2270b9'
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
         color: 'white'
      },
      headerRight: () => (
         <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Ionicons
               style={{ color: 'white', marginRight: 15, marginTop: 5 }}
               size={32}
               onPress={() => { _sendMessage(profile) }} // <--- you can use profile here
               name="ios-mail"
               backgroundColor="#CCC"
            />
         </View>
      )
   })}
/>
```

[react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#specifying-navigationoptions-for-a-screen)

Comment: Unfortunately, the profile object is not known in `App.js`, where I construct the screens.

Comment: Have you tried it though? It does not need to be known in App.js, react navigation allows for constructing screen options based on params the screen receives when you navigate to it.

Comment: Ok you suggest to add that to `component={Profile}` in `App.js`? The profile object is needed in the `onPress` callback of the right header, how can I access it with yout snippet above?

Comment: I've updated the answer using your code snippet for context. `options` prop can be a function that takes { route, navigation } as parameter, giving you access to the profile object from route.params.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found out to work around this - it can be resolved by adding the header within `Profile.js` (where the object is available) and not in `App.js`.

So I've just removed the code for the `headerRight` in `App.js` and instead put this in `Profile.js`:

```
export default function Profile({ route, navigation }) {
   const { profile } = route.params;

   React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
      navigation.setOptions({
         headerRight: () => (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
               <Ionicons
                  style={{ color: 'white', marginRight: 15, marginTop: 5 }}
                  size={32}
                  onPress={_onSendMessage}
                  name="ios-mail"
                  backgroundColor="#CCC"
                  enabled={ profile && profile.core ? true : false}
               />
            </View>
         )
      });
    }, []);
```

This way, no matter from where `Profile.js` is opened, the button callback will have access to the current profile object which is within `Profile.js`' state.

Comment: It's a valid solution. Small drawback, however, is that the button will appear only after the first render, which might not be what you want.